# Cannot access a cookie from a Virtual Directory configures as application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, asp-classic, session-cookies

Setup:

1. The main application is a classic ASP running on app-pool v2.0
2. Reporting application was added later on which was written in .Net 2.0 framework. The classic form model with aspx pages. The application was configured as an application under the main website (from 1)
3. The Reporting application is now to rewritten using MVC 3, and will be deployed similarly on the IIS as an Application under the classic asp website.

Problem,

The login page on the Classic ASP website stores the session ID on a cookie. This cookie is read every time Authentication is required. The MVC application needs to read this cookie but the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies collection doesn't have it. The application (from 2) which needs to be replaced can however easily read it.

Things I have tried,

1. Made sure that the cookie exists by looking at the cookie collection for the main application (from IE8>Tools>Developer Tools> Cache> View Cookie Information).
2. Removed the IsolateApps setting from the the machine key.
3. Made sure the new application is using the same app pool, don't think if that will really cause an issue here.

Appreciate any help with this, Many thanks in advance.

Surya

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the same cookie to fetch values in MVC, check the below link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30723/Handle-session-variable-problems-between-classic-A

Comment: Thanks Ravia, It was an architectural issue. Not sorted yet though. When I initially posted the issue, my MVC was a separate Website sitting besides my main website under the same IIS. I have rectified this and now my MVC application is one sitting as an app under the same Website. Now the problem is it wouldn't run properly (the MVC one). Any ideas? Suggest a separate thread for this?